# Using .where extension method causes duplicates (MVC-LINQ)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to create a partial view to display some data. My controller takes in a `string itemID` and performs a query based on that. When the partial view is called, it displays the same record over and over again.

Note: I changed the name of objects for security purposes.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult someAction(string itemID = "")
{
    //Empty itemID
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemID))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Search");
    }

    var model = _db.someTable
            .Where(r => r.itemID == itemID)
            .OrderBy(r => r.col1)
            .ThenBy(r => r.col2)
            .Take(20);
    return PartialView("_myView", model);
}
```

I have tried removing the `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` methods, but the result remain the same, (Order would not matter since they are duplicates...). When I remove the `.Where` method, it works as expected and displays 20 different records (though, not filtered by any means).

My view was created by Visual Studio using the List template. The view been proven working by removing the `.Where` method from the LINQ statement. Here are the important bits of the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.OperationData>
.
.
.
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.some column)
    </td>
.
.
.
```

Any ideas as to what is wrong with this query?

EDIT: Tried the other LINQ syntax and ended up with the same results:

```
var model = from r in _db.someTable where r.itemID == itemID select r;
```

Comment: Just to be clear; it's listing the same item 20 times?

Comment: My apologies for not being more specific. Yes, the same item is being listed 20 times. I should also note that I have confirmed multiple items with that same itemID exist in the database, so there should be plenty of unique data to show.

Comment: Have tried to use sql profiler to see the sql that is generated from the linq query? that may help in finding the problem.

Comment: I have not. Great idea though. It seems I do not have the correct privileges to use it. I will put in a request to my DBA and try this as soon as possible. In the mean time, I will try using the other LINQ syntax, thought, it probably won't change a thing. I'll report back with the results

Comment: Have you tried to make it `Distinct()` ? Maybe you do have duplicates and the top 20 and order by lets you see these only ?

Comment: I thought that was going to do the trick, but that was not the case. I double, and triple checked my database. There are no duplicates. I inspected the SQL that LINQ created to confirm that it included changes for adding `Distint()`, and it does. Still returns 20 duplicates :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Winner winner chicken dinner!

Turns out the issue was with the mapping of model to table. The table I was working on has a composite key, which I didn't know about... After reading mipe34's bit about primary keys, I decided to do some investigation into the table structure. After discovering the composite keys, I added the mapping for the 2nd key and all works well.

This issue was extremely confusing since the SQL generated by LINQ worked perfectly fine when run in SQL Management Studio.

Thanks all!

Comment: +1 For the follow up. Interesting thought we couldn't have foreseen that given the info we had.

Comment: I had a similar issue when mapping a model to a view (rather than a table).  I needed to include the 2nd table's key as a key in the model code before linq would remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the breakpoint just after the model variable and see what SQL query is generated by LINQ - VS should display it for you. You can also try to execute the query (add .ToList() at the end of the query) to see the actual result, what is in the collection to distinguish if there is a problem in query or view.

Comment: Good advice. I looked through the model to find the SQL version of my LINQ query, and what I found was rather standard looking. It looks like:
`+  model {SELECT TOP (20) 
[Extent1].[Col1] as [Col1}
etc etc etc
WHERE [Extent1].[TOOL_ORDER] = @p__linq__0`
I dont quite understand the first and last bit, where it mentions `+ model` and `@p__linq__0`. I assume the first line tells it to load the results into the model, where as the last line will insert the value of my where clause into the SQL. Looks like it should work... Looking through the model, I get duplicate items...

Comment: no no, + model is just noice from debbuger view (it means click here and i will roll you down other information ;-)) SQL query is only the part in curly brackets. @p__linq__0 is just named parametr for query.

Comment: Try copy the query into sql managemenet, replace @p__linq__0 with actual parameter and hit it on your DB. If you will see results you do not want to see, the problem is with your DB or data not the code (as I suppose).

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after I typed it. Kept getting + and - when copying the query and then I figured out what it was. I had tried your suggestion a little while ago... I get the expected results :-/ Strange thing though... I tried replacing the where clause to work with other columns (huge database w/ huge tables), and **SOME** of those work as expected. Other columns resulted in duplicate records.

Comment: Is ItemId the PRIMARY KEY. If not and there is no UNIQUE INDEX on in there could be duplicates. You can try SELECT DISTINCT in SQL or .Distinct() in LINQ to get unique values.

Comment: Using Distinct didn't do me any good (check out the comments below question). There are more details there that you may have missed. There is a unique index, but its not itemID. I am looking for a list of records with the common attribute of itemID. When running the query in SQL, I get the response I want, but when I let LINQ do the work, I get the first record that matches the itemID, but 20 copies of it(**same PK**). If I remove .Take(20), I get a number of duplicates equal to the amount of rows it should have returned